# vertical scrollbar without a horizontal scrollbar in adf

Tags: oracle-adf

i am using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7 to develop our project in my project i need only vertical scrollbar no need horizontal scrollbar.

my code is given below

```
 <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgls6" layout="scroll">
      <af:tree id="menuTree"
               value="#{pageFlowScope.model}"
               var="menuvar" rowSelection="single"
               initiallyExpanded="true" partialTriggers="::cb2"
               fetchSize="25" autoHeightRows="-1"
               contentDelivery="whenAvailable"
               inlineStyle="height:100%;">
        <f:facet name="nodeStamp">
          <af:commandLink text="#{menuvar.name}" id="cl2"
                          immediate="true">
            <af:dropTarget dropListener="#{DropMenu.execute}">
              <af:dataFlavor flavorClass="java.lang.Object"/>
            </af:dropTarget>
            <af:clientAttribute name="menuBean"
                                value="#{menuvar.index}"/>
            <af:attributeDragSource attribute="menuBean"/>
            <af:resetActionListener/>
          </af:commandLink>
        </f:facet>
      </af:tree>
    </af:panelGroupLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Change `panelGroupLayout` control layout style in to `layout="scroll"` or `layout="horizontal"`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Layout with ADF is always tricky because it depends on your layout structure. I would try to set the `styleClass` property of the `af:tree` to `AFStretchWidth`:

```
<af:tree id="menuTree"
               value="#{pageFlowScope.model}"
               var="menuvar" rowSelection="single"
               initiallyExpanded="true" partialTriggers="::cb2"
               fetchSize="25" autoHeightRows="-1"
               contentDelivery="whenAvailable"
               styleClass="AFStretchWidth">
```

I would also remove `inlineStyle="height:100%;"`. If you want to set the height, you should set a positive value to `autoHeightRows="-1"` like 25.